# pgAdmin 4 - very poor performance of Query-Tool autocomplete, is it normal?

Tags: database, postgresql, autocomplete, pgadmin, querying

Some time ago I've moved from mySql's **phpMyAdmin** to postgres's **pgAdmin 4**.
What I've noticed is that pgAdmin's query tool has very slow autocompletion. Usually it's just faster to type keyword/identifier on your own than waiting till autocompletion will appear.

When I click ctrl+space it takes around 0.5-1 second to appear, horrible.

In compairsion when I use autocompletion in phpMyAdmin, it appears almost immadiately.

Does it work so slowly for you too? Is there any way to fast it up?  Or I have to use some third party program to get faster autocompletion?

[EDIT]

I've also tried the online trial of pgAdmin and here autocompletion is a little bit faster but still not even close to phpMyAdmin's one.

Comment: Is it slow when you autocomplete a keyword like `CREATE` or `DATABASE`, or when you autocomplete a table or column name?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. My autocompletion is slow all the time :(
But if you ask then does it work nice for you?

Comment: I never use pgAdmin. I asked, because if only object names were slow, it might be the slow database connection. If autocompletion of `CREATE` is slow, that seems like a code problem.

Comment: Ok thanks. Are you using postgreSQL too? Maybe you can recommend some better db management software than pgadmin?

Comment: For accessing the database via SQL I only use `psql`. It's simply the best and most comfortable. For managing the database, I use `bash`, `vi` and other operating system tools.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. It is unworkable. Try using DBeaver instead, or have you come to a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no solution, in the end I switched to DBeaver and can tell you it's way better.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, the autocompletion has made pgadmin unusable for me. If I briefly pause to think about a query while I'm navigating, suddenly a list will appear over the SQL I'm looking at, and the arrow key context will be hijacked to navigate that list instead, which is, as you can imagine, jarring.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).